# Moodle Videojs Jquery CurrentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, moodle, video.js

Hi I am stuck on trying to change the videojs player's time. I read on the http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html that I want to use

```
// set
myPlayer.currentTime(120); // 2 minutes into the video
```

to set the video player's time. My code is as is:

```
 var myPlayer = videojs('id_videojs_594c152bdf2e0_html5_api');
 // set current time to 2 minutes into the video
 myPlayer.currentTime(120);
 myPlayer.play();
```

My HTML is

`<video id="id_videojs_594c152bdf2e0_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" title="x.m4v" tabindex="-1">
<source src="http://x/videos/x.m4v" type="video/mp4">http://x/videos/x.m4v
</video>`

My error is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined
**var myPlayer = videojs('#id_videojs_594c152bdf2e0_html5_api');** this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I added

`<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.1.0/video.js"></script>`

in the footer